# How to load custom fonts using CRNA and Expo

Tags: fonts, header, custom-controls, react-navigation, create-react-native-app

**This is my File Structure**

[image: This is my File Structure]

in App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Font } from 'expo';

import Index from './src/index';

export default class App extends Component {
  //checking state for if font is loaded or not.
  state = {
    fontLoaded: false,
  };
   async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'Roboto_medium': require('./src/assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf'),
      'chunky': require('./src/assets/fonts/chunkfive.ttf'),
    });
    //Setting the state to true when font is loaded.
    this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Index />
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to load my font inside of src/screens/home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, List, ListItem, Text } from 'native-base';

// Style Sheet
import styles from '../styles/home';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Davis',
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#177293' },                // The chunky font is not loading from my App.js do I need to import something??
    headerTitleStyle: { color: '#ffffff', alignSelf: 'center', fontFamily: 'chunky' },
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <List>
            <ListItem style={[styles.list, styles.listColor]} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("About")}>
              <Text  style={styles.text}>About</Text>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem style={[styles.list, styles.listColor]} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Estimate")}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Request an Estimate</Text>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem style={[styles.list, styles.listColor]} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Tracker")}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Live Delivery Tracker</Text>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem style={[styles.list, styles.listColor]} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Contact")}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Contact Us</Text>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem style={[styles.list, styles.listColor]} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Testimonials")}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Testimonials</Text>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem style={[styles.list, styles.listColor]} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Login</Text>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem style={[styles.list, styles.listColor]} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Details")}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Job Details</Text>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem style={[styles.list, styles.listColor]} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Requests")}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Requests</Text>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem style={[styles.list, styles.listColor]} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Terms")}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Terms and Conditions</Text>
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to add my custom font into the title of my header. I'm not sure if I need to import it into my home.js like import { chunky } from '../app';
also when I've tried to import it ".../app" doesn't work I thought the first period was to step out of the current file the second one would be to go up to src I just assumed that adding a third period would take me to the root folder and into app... holy crap I just realized capitalization probably matters in the import so not ".../app" but ".../App" for the App.js file in my root folder.

My Results

[image: My Results]

What it looks like now without my custom font

[image: What it looks like now without my custom font]

Answer (score 0):

That error is occured because your screen is using the font before it got loaded. So you have to wait your font to be loaded first before rendering the screen.

```
render() {
  return this.state.fontLoaded && <Index />;
}
```